# How to add html tags in drupal 7 menu?

Tags: 7, routes

I would like to add `<br>` tag or `&nbsp;` character to html menu, but when I type `Home <br> Page`, it does display as plain text, but I want to break that words by two lines.

How can I modify my template.php file with hooks, to allow html tags in menu titles?

Comment: Are all the links in menu the same as that?

Comment: Some links are, some not. For example for "About" page, I don't need separate anything.

Comment: You could certainly do this on the theme level using hook_menu_link but you would have to use a conditional to be specific about which links you want to add <br> to.

Comment: Why can't I just parse and allow that only tag?

Comment: Not sure at what stage you would do that as you have to think that on the theme level your just manipulating output of data whereas what you want to do is not strip a particular tag on user input (in the cms).

Comment: Well, i've found a solution ..
I added `$output = str_replace('&lt;br&gt;', '<br>', $output);` line to the function http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7 and it worked

Comment: Well done, didnt think of that.

Comment: Editing menu.inc is really not a good idea! See @Benajamin's answer, it's a much better solution than breaking core Drupal files.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your problem can be solved using the [Menu HTML](http://drupal.org/project/menu_html) module. It seems to have been designed to solve issues such as the one you describe.

> This very simple module adds a checkbox to the menu item edit form and allows the admin to add html to the menu item title. The idea is to use this for external links for which you want to display a logo of the visited site or simply to add strong on some words.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends on which menus you want to change, but for main and secondary menus you should be able to add this to your theme_preprocess_page function :

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
    foreach ($variables['main_menu'] as &$link) {
        $link['html'] = TRUE;
    }
}
```

for secondary menu replace `['main_menu']` by `['secondary_menu']`

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a generic way, i.e. not relying on specific template changes?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Other method in template.php, for main_menu in the example below:

```
function THEMENAME_links__system_main_menu($vars) {
  foreach ($vars['links'] as &$link) {
    $link['html'] = TRUE;
  }
  return theme_links($vars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In template.php of your theme. This allows html in all menu links.

```
function THEMENAME_menu_link(array $variables) {
  foreach($variables as &$variable) {
    $variable['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;
  }
  return theme_menu_link($variables);
}
```

Comment: can the person who gave -1 explain why?

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work perfectly when added to your (sub-)theme's `template.php`, with `YOURTHEMENAME` replaced by your (sub-)theme's name:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_link($variables) {
  $variables['options']['html'] = TRUE;
  return '<a href="' . check_plain(url($variables['path'], $variables['options'])) . '"' . drupal_attributes($variables['options']['attributes']) . '>' . ($variables['options']['html'] ? $variables['text'] : check_plain($variables['text'])) . '</a>';
}
```

It is an override of the `theme_link()` function defined in `drupal/includes/theme.inc`; only the `$variables['options']['html'] = TRUE;` line was added.

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/112352#comment-5890386

Answer (score 0):

Did not want to use the [Menu HTML](http://drupal.org/project/menu_html) as you need to check mark each menu link.

Here is how I did it programmatically:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_menu_link(array &$variables) {
  $element = &$variables['element'];
  foreach ($element as $value) {
    if (strpos($element['#title'], '<div class="test">') === false) {
      $element['#title'] = '<div class="test">' . $element['#title'] . '</div>';
      $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```